# Using my own class library - C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, projects-and-solutions

I'm developing two projects at once - a class library with classes for things I commonly want in my applications, and an application that uses it. Since I want the library to be easily re-usable by other applications (and virtually stand-alone, even if it wouldn't actually *do* anything on its own), I have placed the library and application in separate solutions. However, although the dependence is one-way, they grow together.

I usually work on these project with multiple instances of Visual Studio open - one for the library, one for the application, and sometimes one for a scrap project where fool around to try new things.

I'd like to have it so that if I first build the library (perhaps requiring a "Release" switch) and then build the application, the latest changes from the library are available in the dll:s imported by the app.

What is a good way to set this up? Can it be done with e.g. NuGet - and if so, how?

(If it matters, I'm currently using the default settings for everything - basically two solutions created with "file->new". I'd like to change as little as possible of that, to lessen the threshold to import the library in my next application.)

Comment: Why won't you include a library project into your application solution?

Comment: @penartur: Mainly because I want this library to "stand alone". When I start working on my next project (which might very well be long before I finish this one, if I ever do), including the library should be possible without doing anything different than what I did the first time.

Comment: But you don't want to have two separate VS windows open, do you?

Comment: @penartur: Actually, I don't mind having the separate VS instances at all - Alt-Tab is an easy-to-reach shortcut... The problem is really that I *want* to import dll:s that are output from a separate solution.

Comment: Let's assume you have the following folder structure: `LibrarySolution\LibraryProject\LibraryProject.csproj`, `Application1\Application1\Application1.csproj`, `Application2\Application2\Application2.csproj`. You probably have `LibrarySolution\LibrarySolution.sln` that only includes `LibraryProject`. But, as long as you develop all three solutions by yourself, I don't see how referencing `LibraryProject.csproj` from `Application1\Application1.sln` and `Application2\Application2.sln` will hurt.

Comment: With this approach you'll be both able to develop `LibraryProject` as a standalone project and as a part of any of the solutions (and to refer to `LibraryProject` from your `ApplicationProjectX`).

Comment: Also, if you're using e.g. `git` to do your versioning, you may consider its **submodules** feature. That is, you have three repositories (`LibrarySolution`, `Application1Solution` and `Application2Solution`); `Application1Solution` repository also has `LibrarySolution` included in `Application1Solution\LibrarySolution`, and `Application1Solution\Application1.sln` includes `Application1Solution\LibrarySolution\LibraryProject\LibraryProject.csproj` (and your `ApplicationProject.csproj` references it).

Comment: I was thinking about using git submodules, but unfortunately Github for Windows (my client of choice) does not have even decent support for it (yet). Perhaps I can learn whatever I need to use the shell for the submoduling stuff...